# Remove sidebar in wordpress (Woocommerce, bazar theme)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

I am trying to remove the default sidebar in wordpress. I tried several method's but none of them worked. I even tried editing the template files.
[image: this is the sidebar I want to get rid of]

I am using woocommerce with the bazar theme.

Answer (score 0):

just rename sidebar.php file in your theme directory and refresh the page if this not gonna help inspect the sidebar pick up the main div class name search the theme and comment the code . one of the easiest but not recommended way is to display none the div in style.css

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It turned out that the setting for changing the sidebars was well hidden in the theme. I eventually found it and fixed it.